# Max height for fixed background image?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set a max height value to a background image that uses `background-attachment: fixed` ?

I want to use `background-size:cover` to cover entire div but instead the image covers the whole viewport instead of just div when its fixed. I thought I could set a max height value to the background image but not sure if this is possible?

See fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wcn0wrm3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. This is how `background-attachment: fixed` works - it sets your background-image to cover the whole viewport. `background-size:cover` in this case is totally useless. What do you want to achive with this styling?